# textbox autocomplete working very slow

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I have added autocomplete option to my program. It is working fine, but it is performing very slow. I am adding things to my collection and this part is slowing my program down.

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{

     Line main = new Line();
     main.LeftColumn = Time;
     main.Middle= returnValue;
     main.RightColumn = User_Description;
     list3.Add(main);

    //Here I add everything to my collection
     if (main.Middle.Source.Device != null)
     {
           suggest.Add(main.Middle.Source.Device);
     }
     if (main.Middle.ID.Device != null)
     {
           suggest.Add(main.Middle.ID.Device);
     }
}
```

I add my thing to collection I have to get access to it by showing object of my class `Line` called `main` than `Middle` is field of this class which is connected with other class `Source` or `ID` in which there are my string fields that I want to add to collection.
Basically when file that I am working with are small (up to 700 lines) it is not working very slow, but when I put file with for example (3000 line) it takes some time to add all this things, during this process I can't use my application.

How can I make it work faster? Is it possible? If something will be not clear, just ask me and I will try to explain more.

Comment: I am using it but I didn't put part of the code responsible for this. I thought that it is not necessary to put it here. I use it because I am reading txt files in my program.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to make it work faster. Now process of adding everything to collection is slowing my program very much.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I need StreamReader, because I must be able to choose files I want in my program.

Comment: I still don't think that it will make adding process to collection work faster. Because when I comment out lines about collection, my program is working very fast. The problem is with this strings inside classes. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You trim down your file to minimal size. And check the size of file if file size is less than 1 MB. I think for 3000 lines it would be less than that. Once you do this than load file in memory and hold it in collection and than perform operation on variable and try to read all file in single go instead of reading it line by line(Better use File.ReadAllLines() for one time reading). Perform this while windows is loading in background. I think this will drastically change your application performance.

Use Dictionary if possible instead of List because accessing element from a dictionary is much faster compared to list. I don't know your application logic so can't say whether you can use dictionary or not. So take decision accrodingly.

Please check the memory constraints with proper data in file.
If this does not solve your problem provide some more detail about your code. I will try to simulate and help you out.